# JavaFX TableView double selection in a filebrower

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently working on a program with a filebrowser. I implemented it using a tableView which shows what's in the current folder.

If I have a folder A which contains 1, 2 and 3. If I click on A. It will open A and **also** 1 because the first item is still selected.

What I think is happening : A gets focus then become selected, it changes the view and the focus is still on the first item which becomes selected.

An eventListener tracks the selection changes:

```
table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<FileItem>() {

   @Override
   public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends FileItem> observable,
                       FileItem oldValue, FileItem newValue) {
      // newValue may be null when the list is cleared (in that case do not try to download the document)
      if (table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null ) {
          Path path = Paths.get(newValue.getFullPath());
          if (newValue.isDirectory()) {
              showDirectory(path);
          }
```

And the showfolder():

```
public void showDirectory(Path path){
    try{
        DirectoryStream<Path> dir = Files.newDirectoryStream(path);
        table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        if(path.getRoot().equals(path)){
            parentButton.setVisible(false);
        }
        else{
            parentButton.setVisible(true);
        }
        fileList.clear();
        for(Path file:dir){
            FileItem fileItem = new FileItem(file);
            fileList.add(fileItem);
        }
        currentDirectory = path.toString();
        pathLabel.setText(currentDirectory);
    }
    catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I already tried `table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection()`

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Alexis Benoist.